# Encrypt entire site - request access

Tags: security

How can I encrypt my entire site?

I also need to require password and username to access site. When visitors are accessing site, they will be redirected to a login page where they can also request membership. How to implement that?

Comment: I have tried the module "require login" - however when I activate the module you can only access login - not user registration. The implication is obvious.. 

Thanks for taking your time to answer by the way!

Comment: This is two separate questions. I recommend asking them in two separate question postings, as one post with multiple questions is depreciarted here.  (Just edit the post and delete one of them - then repost as a new question). Also include what you've tried so far in the *question*, not in a comment.

Comment: If you uncheck the "access content" permission for anon and set the 403 page to user/register that may go some way to achieving that.

Comment: But what do you mean by "encrypt entire site"? SSL? Or encrypted content in database so server admins can't read? PGP keys for each user? Or all you really need is to deny access, not encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do two-way encryption in Drupal, but there are two modules that will extend Drupal to support encryption:

- [**Encrypt**](https://drupal.org/project/encrypt)
- [**AES**](http://drupal.org/project/aes)

**Encrypt:**

- Includes multiple encryption methods from simple to complex depending on libraries available on the server.
- Focused on being a simple API that doesn't do much on its own.
- Sub-module [Field Encrypt](https://drupal.org/project/field_encrypt) let you use it to encrypt fields *without* coding (but beta only, no stable release of this one).
- Uses [**CTools**](https://drupal.org/project/ctools) plugins for encryption methods and key providers.
- Contains unit tests for all the features.
- Stable Drupal 7 release, about 1400 installed sites.

**AES:**

- Includes support for one encryption method (AES).
- Built in functionality focused on two-way password encryption. Other uses requires coding by means of the API.
- Requires use of the PHP extension *mcrypt* or the *phpseclib* (PHP Secure Communications Library) external library.
- Has no built-in testing.
- Stable Drupal 7 release, about 3000 installed sites.

You should be able to encrypt the entire site by using either of these modules and create a simple custom module that uses the hook system to encrypt content before it is stored in the datebase and decrypt as part of rendering content.

You may even do it without creating a custom module by means of **Encrypt** with sub-module [**Field Encrypt**](https://drupal.org/project/field_encrypt) - if you find the beta-realese of the latter stable enough for your uses.

(PS: I can tell you how to restrict access as well, but that need to be a separate question).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to encrypt images as well (I had to do this recently for passport photos attached to users accounts) then I found a solution using the Storage API module together with the encrypt module.

First set the image field's storage backend to be the database.

Then I had to modify the db.inc file included with the storage_api module.

First change the `serviceInstanceCreate` function to add a line to encrypt the data before inserting into the DB.

```
public function serviceInstanceCreate(Storage $storage, $uri) {
  $active = $this->setActiveDB();

  $data = file_get_contents($uri);
  $data = encrypt($data);

  db_insert($this->settings['table'])
    ->fields(array(
      'file_id' => $storage->file_id,
      'contents' => $data,
      ))
    ->execute();

  return $storage->file_id;
}
```

And then in `serviceInstanceGetContents` check if the contents is encrypted, and if it is decrypt it.

```
public function serviceInstanceGetContents($reference) {
  $active = $this->setActiveDB();

  $contents = db_select($this->settings['table'])
    ->fields($this->settings['table'], array('contents'))
    ->condition('file_id', $reference)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchField();

  if ($contents === FALSE) {
    throw new StorageException();
  }

  // check if this is encrypted and decrypt if necessary
  $unserialized = unserialize($contents);
  if(is_array($unserialized)) $contents = decrypt($contents);

  return $contents;
}
```